# Large List and a Few Unique Item Permisions

Tags: sharepoint-online

In a SharePoint Online list, what are the boundaries when it comes to breaking inheritance on a few list items?

The list has ~10k items.
At times, 50 items will need to have their permissions updated to allow for auditors to view them. Once the audit is complete, the list items will have their permissions reverted to inherit from the parent list.

The auditors belong to one SharePoint group and non-auditors belong to another group.

50 items have auditors and non-auditor permissions assigned to them. the remaining list items inherit from the parent list.  would this equate to 2 uniquie permissions or 50+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store up to **30 million items or files** in a list or library.

When a list, library, or folder contains more than **100,000 items**, you can't break permissions inheritance on the list, library, or folder. Nor can you re-inherit permissions on it. However, you can still break inheritance on the individual items within that list, library, or folder, up to the maximum number of unique permissions in the list or library .

For large lists, design to have as few **unique permissions** as possible and remain below **5,000** in total.

However, when a list **view** shows more than **5000 items**, you may run into a list view threshold error.

Reference:

- [SharePoint limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits)
- [Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

Comment: Thank you.  Given the scenario above, would that equal ~50 unique permissions or ~2?  (i'll update the question to clarify)

Comment: Hi Taco_Buffet. If there are 50 items assigned with auditors and non-auditor permissions, the remaining list items are inherited from the parent list. Then the list has 50 unique permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on MS guidelines, breaking inheritance at the List, Library, Folder, and Individual item levels depends on the *maximum number of unique permission* allowed and also the item count at that level.

The item count limit at list, library and folder level is: **100,000**

Unique Permissions allowed at the list and library level is: **50,000**

The recommended unique permissions is: **5,000**

Based on your requirements, I don't think you will have any issues.

Please visit the following articles for details

1. Customize Permissions [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)
2. Breaking Inheritance [Issue Resolution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/error-share-break-inheritance)